# strange factorization of a simple combination of j-invariant coefficients

Tags: nt.number-theory, j-invariant

I am just curious: is it accidental that $744^2+744\cdot 3-196884\cdot2=162000$ has only the small primes $2$, $3$ and $5$ in its factorization?

Comment: Probably as accidental as $744^2+744\cdot 3 -196884\cdot 5 = - 2^2 \cdot  3^7 \cdot 7^2$ and $744^2-744\cdot 3 -196884\cdot 6 = - 2^4 \cdot 3^2 \cdot  5^4 \cdot 7$.

Comment: Seven is a medium-sized prime.